# simple q on 'while' method in Ruby

Tags: loops, while-loop, include

i am writing a "while" loop method like below:

objective: find the position of the first letter that's a vowel in a give word "stackoverflow"

```
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u",]
word = "stackoverflow"
n = 0
    while vowels.include? word[n] == false
    n += 1
    end
print n
```

question: why would n return to be 0? as opposed to 2 which is the first "o" letter in "stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence in your while loop evaluation. Try this 
(vowels.include? word[n]) == false
which will evaluate your check for a vowel and then compare it to false.

You face a different issue if there is no vowel in "word"